# Как правильно обернуть дивом несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имею:

```
<div id="2" class="slider">
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
</div>
```

Таких  более сотни.
Я оборачиваю в свой див разными группами в разных количествах.

```
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wow-ggg')];

const div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.classList.add('test');
document.body.append(div1); // вставляем див, куда нужно
div1.append(...items.slice(0, 5));

const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.classList.add('test');
document.body.append(div2); // вставляем див, куда нужно
div2.append(...items.slice(5, 10));
```

..... и так далее

это работает
НО
мне нужно чтобы это все оставалось в пределах моего id="2" class="slider"

```
<div id="2" class="slider">
    ..... чтобы это все здесь и оставалось и непермещалось никуда
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wow-ggg')];
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

const div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.append(...items.slice(0, 5));

const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.append(...items.slice(5, 10));

slider.innerHTML = '';
slider.append(div1); // вставляем див, куда нужно
slider.append(div2); // вставляем див, куда нужно
```

```css
.slider {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.slider > div {
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 2px;
}

.wow-ggg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="2" class="slider">
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
    <div class="wow-ggg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как это сделать используя только  id="2"

Comment: @Oiki изучить селекторы и корректно вставить селектор вместо `.slider`

Comment: вот так правильно будет- https://jsfiddle.net/profy/xwosnjfu/183/

Comment: т.е. у меня  id="slider2", и я указываю вместо .slider  пишу   #slider2

Comment: @Oiki да, так сработает. Jsfiddle подтверждает это если запустить код)

Comment: фух.. Ж))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж тут присутствует метка jquery, то для оборачивания элементов есть метод `wrapAll()`.

```js
let items = $("#2 .wow-ggg");
items.slice(0,5).wrapAll('<div class="red">');     
items.slice(5,8).wrapAll('<div class="green">');
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2" class="slider">
    <div class="wow-ggg">1</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">2</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">3</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">4</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">5</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">6</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">7</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">8</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">9</div>
    <div class="wow-ggg">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: какаято стрнность , а на моем сайте не работает